# SpringBoot and JPA Testing

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

After a few days on trying to figure out my problem, I am thoroughly confused.   Here is what I am doing.  I am running a Spring Boot project using JPA.  I have gotten the JDBCTemplate solution working for one table in a PostgreSQL database.  I have tested it with no problem.  Now I moved to the major portion of the project with six tables.  I chose JPA as there is mostly CRUD operations.

When I build and test using SpringBoot, I am getting the below two errors for my AcceptanceCriteriaTest.  I see Spring cannot initialize the Abstract which leads to believer I do not have my annotations right.  The other error is I ca not find my Persistence Unit identified.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Russ

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.company.me.batch.test.eao.AbstractJPATest
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:147)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And this is the second error from the test:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:147)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named jpaReqChgPU
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at org.company.me.batch.test.eao.AbstractJPATest.<clinit>(AbstractJPATest.java:25)
    ... 41 more
```

Here is how I configured the table using JPA:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="accCriteria_tbl", schema="iaReqChanges")
@SequenceGenerator(name="AcceptCritera_SEQ_GEN", schema="iaReqChanges", sequenceName = "accCriteria_tbl_accCri_id_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
public class AcceptanceCriteria implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="AcceptCritera_SEQ_GEN")
    @Column(name="accCri_id", updatable = false)
    private Long accCri_id;
```

Now I want to test my Entity.  This is my test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@PropertySource(name="X", value={"classpath:/applicationConfig.properties"})
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApplicationConfig.class)
public class AcceptCriteriaTest extends AbstractJPATest {




    @Test
    public void testCreateAcceptCriteria(){
        String accCriteriaAction="Give Mary a little Lamb";
        String accCriteriaControl="Mary's lamb must be white as snow";
        String accAcceptanceCriteria="Does Mary have a little lamb.  IS is white as snow?";
        String busRequirement="Mary must be happy with her lamb that is white as snow";
        Timestamp lastModified = new java.sql.Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());

        AcceptanceCriteria acceptCriteria = new AcceptanceCriteria();
        acceptCriteria.setAccAccptCriteria(accAcceptanceCriteria);
        acceptCriteria.setAccAction(accCriteriaAction);
        acceptCriteria.setBusRequirement(busRequirement);
        acceptCriteria.setLastModified(lastModified);

        AbstractJPATest.entityManager.persist(acceptCriteria);


        AcceptanceCriteria acceptCriteria2 = AbstractJPATest.entityManager.find(AcceptanceCriteria.class, acceptCriteria);
        assertTrue((acceptCriteria.getAccAction().equals(accCriteriaAction)));

    }
```

This is my Abstract Class:

```
public abstract class AbstractJPATest extends TestCase {


    static final EntityManagerFactory EMF = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpaReqChgPU");

    //@PersistenceContext
    //protected static EntityManager em = null;


    @PersistenceContext
    protected static TestEntityManager entityManager = new TestEntityManager(EMF);
```

This is my ApplicationConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableConfigurationProperties(LiquibaseProperties.class)
@PropertySource(name="X", value={"classpath:/applicationConfig.properties"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationConfig {

    private static final Logger slf4jLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationConfig.class);



    @Autowired
    LiquibaseProperties properties;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    /* Data Source configuration is in applicationConfig.properties file */
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${init-db:false}")
    private String initDatabase;



    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        properties.setChangeLog("classpath:/db/changelog/postgres-changelog-master.xml");
        liquibase.setChangeLog(this.properties.getChangeLog());
        liquibase.setContexts(this.properties.getContexts());
        liquibase.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        liquibase.setDefaultSchema(this.properties.getDefaultSchema());
        liquibase.setDropFirst(this.properties.isDropFirst());
        liquibase.setShouldRun(this.properties.isEnabled());
        return liquibase;

    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {

        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }


    /* This is used for the SQLDAO*/
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource)
    {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    /*
    @Bean(name="PlaformTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {

        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);

    }
    */

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName("jpaReqChgPU");
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaDialect(jpaDialect());
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("org.itaa.ia.batch");
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaPropertyMap(hibernateJpaProperties());
        slf4jLogger.debug("emf",  entityManagerFactory.toString());
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "jpaVendorAdapter")
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        return vendorAdapter;

    }


    @Bean(name = "jpaDialect")
    public JpaDialect jpaDialect() {
        return new HibernateJpaDialect();
    }

    @Bean(name = "persistenceExceptionTranslation")
     PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }


    private Map<String, ?> hibernateJpaProperties() {
        HashMap<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        //properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "false");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files", "insert-data.sql");
        properties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");

        properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "2");
        properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", "5");
        properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "300"); // 5mins

        return properties;
    }


    @Bean(name="jpaTransManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        //org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager
        //JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
        jpaTransactionManager.setPersistenceUnitName("jpaReqChgPU");
        jpaTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        jpaTransactionManager.setJpaDialect(jpaDialect());
        jpaTransactionManager.setJpaPropertyMap(hibernateJpaProperties());
        //jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication();
        springApplication.setWebEnvironment(false);
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationConfig.class, args);
    }
```

Comment: IMO, you can try getting rid of - extends AbstractJPATest from the declaration - public class AcceptCriteriaTest extends AbstractJPATest. As you are loading - @SpringBootTest(classes = ApplicationConfig.class) - all those dependencies should be available to you.

Comment: Also try using @ TestPropertySource instead of @ PropertySource.

Comment: Can try making the EntityManager non-static and inject it instead of manually creating it? I'm suspecting that when the class is loaded and static fields initialized, your Spring application context isn't created yet.

Comment: Thank you.  I removed the Abstract class along with removing the static EntityManager these changes got me pass the issues.  Now I am stuck with the test not seeing the entity "AcceptanceCritiera" in the test.